# Add /n to text in Wordpress (ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have situation where my output from Textarea field (acf) needs to be like this::

```
lorem ipsum blabla\nblbala\n\nlorem lorem
```

This is my ACF text field:

```
<?php the_field( 'content_new' ); ?>
```

this returns content like this:

```
lorem ipsum blabla <br> 
blbala <br> nlorem lorem
```

So my question is, can I output `/n` instead of `<br>` like on example:

```
lorem ipsum blabla\nblbala\n\nlorem lorem
```

Thank you all

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/textarea/#settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check that your textarea field setting new lines is set to "No formatting"

Also you can do this

```
<?php echo str_replace('<br>', '\n', get_field( 'content_new' )); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got this error: Warning: str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 1 given

Comment: Sorry let me update.
Here we go.
This one have to be fine.
Please try